# Cannot select the region in Google Fusion Table?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

The problem is that when I want to draw the FusionTableLayer and select the whole World it draws the shape over all countries except one Russian Region.
I want to select it as well.

```
new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  query: {
    select: 'geometry',
    from: '1N2LBk4JHwWpOY4d9fobIn27lfnZ5MDy-NoqqRpk',
  },
  styles: [{
    polygonOptions: {
      fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
      strokeColor: "#FFFFFF",
      fillOpacity: 0.8
    }
  }]
});
```

JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/eqx5h9x4/

Answer (score 0):

Kaliningrad isn't represented in your KML, it would appear. When I add a map to your table in the FT web app that area isn't shown as a polygon either.